# Why is this appearing in my website print preview?

Tags: php, html, concrete5

I have a website development problem.

My website, when in print preview and when printed, shows:

> (/)

which appears near the top of the page, and it isn't in any of my website files.

The website is in Concrete5, but I style it with my own LESS.

Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: use developer's tools to highlight it and look for it in the code.

Comment: You can't do that in a print preview.

Comment: right click -> view source -> search for the string. There is no way anyone on here can help as we dont have access to the code in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browsers append the URL to a link when printing. To turn this off, add this to your site's stylesheet:

```
@media print {
    a[href]:after {
        content: "" !important;
    }
}
```